# Multiple urls for single file htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo

i m using htaccess for seo-friendly urls and i m facing this problem:-

```
RewriteRule sign-up                 sign-up.php?optFile=register
RewriteRule update-profile          sign-up.php?optFile=register&action=update
RewriteRule error-update-profile    sign-up.php?optFile=register&action=update&info=error
RewriteRule info-update-profile     sign-up.php?optFile=register&action=update&info=info
RewriteRule success-update-profile  sign-up.php?optFile=register&action=update&info=success
```

No matter which link i choose, they all redirect to 1st url.

Please, can anyone help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sign-up/?$                 sign-up.php?optFile=register [L]
RewriteRule ^update-profile/?$          sign-up.php?optFile=register&action=update [L]
RewriteRule ^error-update-profile/?$    sign-up.php?optFile=register&action=update&info=error [L]
RewriteRule ^info-update-profile/?$     sign-up.php?optFile=register&action=update&info=info [L]
RewriteRule ^success-update-profile/?$  sign-up.php?optFile=register&action=update&info=success [L]
```